# Textarea over button, button not clickable

Tags: css

I have put textarea over button, but it made button not clickable at the positions where textarea is. How can I disable textarea selection and make button clickable on whole surface, while textarea is still visible?
The same with small image (icon). If I put icon over button it will not be clickable on that position.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none` on the overlapping objects which will let you "click through" it, i.e. click the element below it.

More information: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: it disables selection of textarea (nice) but does not allow button click

Comment: actually it's working, I forgot to put it on parent div. I will accept your answer, thanks!